# Show $S^2 \vee \mathbb{R}^2$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Show $S^2 \vee \mathbb{R}^2$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee \mathbb{R}^3$.

So, i'm having a little bit of trouble doing this. I know that $\mathbb{R}^m \ncong \mathbb{R}^n$ if $n \neq m$.

When showing things arn't homemorphic, you can assume they are homeomorphic, subtract a point and find a contradiction. I don't believe that trick works with homotopy equivalence. Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

Answer: $S^2 \vee \mathbb{R}^2$ is indeed homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee \mathbb{R}^3$, because we can deformation retract both of the euclidean spaces to the point at wedge is formed, and so both of those spaces are equivalent to just $S^2$

Comment: For distinct $m, n$, $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ aren't homeomorphic, but they are homotopy equivalent -- unless I'm wrong the spaces $S^2 \vee \mathbb{R}^2$ and $S^2 \vee \mathbb{R}^3$ should be homotopy equivalent by a similar argument.

Comment: They are both homotopy equivalent to $S^2$.

Comment: Right, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homotopy equivalent to a single point because it is contractible, so $S^2 \vee x_0 \cong S^2$?

Edit: aah it contracts to the point where the wedge is formed

Comment: Here is an interesting problem: can the wedge of two contractible spaces be noncontractible?

Comment: @ConnorMalin , you might be interested in the Griffith's space, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116980/is-the-wedge-sum-of-two-cones-over-the-hawaiian-earring-contractible .

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom You should write an official answer.

Answer (score 1):

As OP has edited into their question, the answer is that the two spaces are indeed homotopy equivalent.